# Read open sound control's packets in Smalltalk VisualWorks 7.9.1

Tags: smalltalk, osc, visualworks

Does anyone have an idea where to find an open sound control reader for visualworks?

I inspected the Siren project and the OSC VW project but they are made to send OSC packets however my objectif is to read some OSC packets coming from TuioReactivision simulator.

Thx in Advance.